# Upload a Dropbox file to InkFilepicker

Tags: dropbox, filepicker.io

I'm trying to upload a file using the Dropbox API to Ink Filepicker, but I can't find any documentation on doing things like this.

It's done in the backend using Ruby rather than with the Javascript frontend because it needs to automatically upload new photos (Specifically inside the '/Camera_Uploads' folder) as they're added.

Has anyone had experience with doing something like that? One solution I saw was sharing the file, and then uploading them with the Filepicker REST API, but that seems like a bad way to approach this.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your approach of sending a URL to File Picker is a good one, but I would suggest using a `media` link instead of a `share` link. [Media links](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#media) expire after four hours, so they're a good alternative to permanently sharing a file.

In Ruby, the method you want is [`DropboxClient.media`](https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-ruby-sdk-1.6.1-docs/DropboxClient.html#method-i-media).